# Retrieving group by result with arrays in mongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have mongo documents in the following format. I want to get the devices_ids for each unique phone_numbers but my mongo query is not giving proper result.

Can anyone point out my problem ?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cf21562e7b232d022f334e871"),
    "uid" : 5,
    "device_id" : "352136234234325",
    "name" : "user1",
    "email" : ["user1@mail.com" ],
    "phone_number" : [
        "+919890273451"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cf21562e7b2d032422f334e872"),
    "uid" : 15,
    "device_id" : "3521360123444",
    "name" : "user1",
    "email" : [ "user1@mail.com"],
    "phone_number" : [
        "+919890273451"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cf21562342e7b2d022f334e873"),
    "uid" : 51,
    "device_id" : "352136067208559",
    "name" : "user1",
    "email" : [ "user1@mail.com"],
    "phone_number" : [
        "+919890273451"
    ]
}
```

My expected output is

```
{
"phone_number" : "+919890273451",
device_ids : ["352136067208559","3521360123444","352136234234325"]}
}
```

I have tried this query:

```
db.contact.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$phone_number"
},
{$group: {"_id":"$phone_number"},
device_ids: { $push:  { user: "$device_id"} }
}
], {
allowDiskUse:true,
cursor:{}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `$push` you don't need to specify touple name - just push plain value.

Please see below:

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
        $unwind : "$phone_number"
    }, {
        $group : {
            _id : "$phone_number",
            device_ids : {
                $addToSet : "$device_id"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks professor. Its working now. But gives repetative device_id in $push. Can we make it unique element array.

Comment: use `$addToSet` insted `$push` - forgot about that :-) @VigneshPrajapati